# I have configured the sharepoint online people search , but getting weird search result

Tags: sharepoint-online, people-search

I have configured the sharepoint online people search , but getting  weird search result , for example in search box if i put "Kin" and enter it shows people starting with Ken and none of them is correct match..
[image]

and on enter this is the result set
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are seeing Phonetic Name Matches ("kin" sounds like "Ken"). This is standard behavior on a People Result Source.

Comment: How can i avoid it or force to show the real match , any help will be highly appreciable

Comment: Turn off Phonetic Name Matching and Nick Name Matching in the People Search Results web part. Is that screenshot a custom solution?

Comment: yes, i have customized the template .Thanks for your suggestion